# compare two char in matlab : char 105 and char 99

Tags: string, matlab, comparison, char, string-comparison

I'm trying to compare two strings (from matlab)

```
the first one has as type : 1*99 char
the second one has as type : 1*105 char
```

how could I perform conversion to be able to make comparison ?

thanks

Comment: What do you want to compare? In other words, can you give us an example for two strings that should be equal, and two that are different?

Comment: the first one is a message and the second one also but seems not to have same type , the first one 1*99 char and the second 1*105 char  and I ould like to compare these two messages

Comment: Could you tell us what you mean by compare? The term in itself is ambiguous; see Matlab's [strcmp](http://www.mathworks.co.uk/help/techdoc/ref/strcmp.html) vs Java's [String.CompareTo](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#compareTo%28java.lang.String%29).

Comment: Can you give us examples strings? Maybe you want to trim leading and lagging spaces, otherwise surely strings of different lengths are not the same...

Answer (score 1):

The question is quite ambiguous (different size does not imply different *type* etc.), but I understood that you want to cut leftmost or rightmost elements of the second char vector (here `SecondCharVector`) to match the size of first char vector (here `FirstCharVector`).

Some example char vectors:

% `FirstCharVector` is 1x99 char vector.

```
FirstCharVector = [ repmat('abcdefghij', 1, 9), 'abcdefghi' ];
```

% `SecondCharVector` is 1x105 char vector.

```
SecondCharVector = [ repmat('abcdefghij', 1, 10), 'abcde' ];
```

To cut off the leftmost elements (head of string) of `SecondCharVector` to make it same size as `FirstCharVector`:

```
SecondCharVector(1:(size(SecondCharVector, 2)-size(FirstCharVector, 2))) = [];
```

Or, to cut off the rightmost elements (tail of string) of `SecondCharVector` to make it same size as `FirstCharVector`:

```
SecondCharVector(size(FirstCharVector, 2)+1:end) = [];
```

Please note that this code assumes that `SecondCharVector` is longer in horizontal dimension than `FirstCharVector`, and this in not checked.